# Why is the transition timing working on color, but not text-align?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add transition timing when switching the text alignment via :hover. The transition is added to the color properly, but not the text alignment.

example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/trevorbooth/pen/LqqNor)

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff4000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}

div:hover>h1 {
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: right;
  transition: .6s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot animate text-align : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 2):

I guess it was just the CSS Working Group decided not to implement it for whatever reasons. But there are other ways around, see the following demo by using position and transform tricks.

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff4000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}

div:hover > h1 {
  color: #ddd;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Another approach is to animate `width`.

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff4000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  width: 0;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}

div:hover > h1 {
  color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`transform: translateX()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX)

`text-align` is not [animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) but [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and `transforms` are -- the latter being the better choice because it's [less GPU/CPU intensive](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/) than the former. The following is a what was added as the first leg of the animation in the demo.

> ```
> transform:translateX(300px);
> transition: transform .6s ease-in;
> ```

---

### Demo

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff4000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform .6s ease-out;
}

div:hover>h1 {
  color: #ddd;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(300px);
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```